# How get a list from List of Lists

Tags: arrays, list, groovy

How get a list from array of arrays?

I have a List of Lists, like: `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`.

I want to have a List that contains all first elements from my List.

For example in my example, I want to have a `list = [1,1,1]`.

Comment: `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` is a List of Lists, not an Array of Arrays (in Groovy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know you always have an list of lists (i.e. the inner list always exists), you could do it like this:

```
def lists = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
def result = lists.collect { it[0] }
assert result == [1,1,1]
```

Comment: Or `arrays*.getAt( 0 )`

Comment: I used "arrays*.getAt( 0 )" and its ok. Thank you.

Comment: @Jils You should probably accept this answer rather than mine :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you also might want to get the second/third elements of each List, you can also use `transpose`:

```
def input = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
def output = input.transpose()

// All the lists are joined by element index
assert output == [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]

// Grab the first one (1,1,1)
assert output[ 0 ] == [ 1,1,1 ]
```

Comment: I don't need to use yet, but its great to know how to do.
thanks